# How to fix a Build error 'Multiple commands produce' on Xcode 14, MacBookPro M1

Tags: xcode, react-native

Tech data:

- macOS: Monterrey 12.5.1
- Xcode: 14
- cocoapods:1.11.3
- node: 16.17.0
- React Native: 0.59
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGz4R.png)

Comment: Try deleting derived data folder and cleaning the build folder. Also always provide error logs in reproducible (text) format and not as screenshots

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.